# Miktex and beamer: Error: \beamer@endinputifotherversion

Tags: beamer

I have downloaded MiKTeX (on Windows 10). The `.tex` files for papers and posters compile well but `beamer` does not work.

Here is the header of my .tex file:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{amssymb}  %   MATH
\usepackage{amsmath}  %   MATH
\usepackage{latexsym} %   MATH
\usepackage{amsthm}   %   MATH
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{bm}         % per scrivere in grassetto i caratteri matematici
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

I receive the following error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence. 
l.1 \beamer@endinputifotherversion
                                   {3.26pt}
```

How can this problem be fixed?

Joab Winkler

Answer (score 84):

You've changed `beamer` versions and not deleted you auxiliary files. Older versions of `beamer` add `\beamer@endinputifotherversion` to the `.nav`  and `.toc` files to check for version changes. This was removed in recent versions as it tends to cause more trouble than it fixes. As such, you can either

- Just press Return and let the run continue or
- Delete the `.nav` and `.toc` files

In either case, the issue will disappear at the next run.

Comment: Hi @Joseph Wright. 

I did both of the above it refused to work. I have mac laptop with version 2.2.16 (where the tex file runs without any issue) and a windows version 2.2.16 (where it refuses to work). Do you know what might be the problem?

Thanks,
Nishant.

Comment: @NishantChandgotia I have no idea what version number you are referring to: current `beamer` is 3.56!

Comment: Maybe that is the issue. I have 2018/12/02 v3.55. I tried updating it but I am somehow unable to do that.

Comment: FWIW, this answer worked great for me. Beamer version 3.40 (Debian 9/Stretch).

Comment: It worked for me on Linux (texlive 11:svn65161-77.fc39) too. Run the command twice to get the desired output. At least if you choose the first option (Just press Return...).